# php 5.3.24 - cli differs from http while using function()[i]

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Why array indexing `[i]` won't work on functions while invoking the script from command line? (*`PHP` version is on question in order to filter views.*)

### Test case:

```
<?php

echo explode( ' ', php_uname() )[0];

?>
```

### Command line output:

```
> php -n -f borrar.php
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in borrar.php on line 3
```

### Browser output:

```
Windows
```

### EDIT

XAMPP php version was different from another PHP version that was previously installed in the system. That explains why I got different behaviours.

Comment: What does `> php -v` gives you? (so much for your debugging skills :))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array dereferencing doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544853/array-dereferencing-doesnt-work)

Comment: @hakre `PHP` version is on the question title. If you want all the `php -v` output here it is: `PHP 5.3.24 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2013 18:32:42) Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies`.

Comment: See the linked duplicate if you have any doubt in which PHP version that works and in which versions not. Like you wrote PHP 5.3 does not supports this, you need PHP 5.4. On the commandline you do not have PHP 5.4. On your webservers module you have.

Comment: @hakre despite the version, why is working from web request. If it doesn't work it shouldn't work at all.

Comment: @Sebastion add `echo PHP_VERSION, "<br>\n";` in your PHP file to output the PHP version in your PHP file. You can easily test that.

Comment: Are you sure your apache's php is the same version as your cli php?

Comment: @hakre, it says `5.4.7`. This guys at `xampp`... why.

Comment: @Sebastian: Q: Why - A: Because it has been configured this way. Q: Why has it been configured this way? - A: Ask the person who has configred it. Q: That was me. I have no clue. - A: We can't help you to recover your memory. Next time write on your webblog how you did things so you can search them later via google.

Comment: @hakre, `define:rhetorical`

Comment: Yes, that was guessing in the blue but I hope it explains that I can not say why it was done that way, it's not my computer. I would fire a question in the XAMPP user forums or maybe better IRC and ask for hints how to aling those again. This requires a bit of system configuration, normaly setting the path environment variable to a new directory where the CLI binary of PHP is located. It can be that XAMPP does not change this well with updates.

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm and http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: @hakre I voted to close my own question. I can't determine how the system was configured and it was impossible to me know that another PHP installation was made. My bad was assuming that php version were equals.